# Where's the Edit Points Bar?! [LibreOffice Calc]

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to edit a curve. LibreOffice Calc help says I need the Edit Points Bar. It also says it will come up when I click "edit control points". It's a big fat lie. Where's my Edit Points Bar?!

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately in Calc, the edit points bar is not functioning. It would be perfect, if you could put a comment in the related bug entry: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36943

This would show that there are people who need that feature. Maybe this directs developers on that issue.